# Emacs (Aquamacs) web-mode not automatically activating for HTML files

Tags: html, emacs, elisp, aquamacs

I've installed `web-mode` using a package manager. When I open a html file, it does not activate `web-mode` automatically. However, I can start `web-mode` manually using `M-x web-mode` so I'm sure it is installed correctly.

I am using the following lines in my `Preferences.el` file:

```
;;configure web-mode
(require 'web-mode) 
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html$" . web-mode))
```

I have many other configurations in my Preferences.el file and these all work so Aquamacs is definitely recognizing this file.

Does anyone have any further suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If you replace your pattern with `"\\.html?\\'"`, does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I've discovered that it enters web-mode when I create a new html file, but not when I open one.

Comment: That's very weird. If you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`, then eval the statements in your question, then open an HTML file, does it work?

Comment: @soarjay does an other major is loaded ? Moreover could you put your config lines at the end of your Preferences.el ?