# web-mode won't start automatically in Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I can't seem to get the configuration to work properly, only if I create a new HTML it goes into web-mode, any other way it goes into de default html-mode.

I'm using Aquamacs 3.2 GNU Emacs 2.4.4.51.2

Though I have had this same problem with previous versions.

Here's my config file (Preferences.el):

```
;; This is the Aquamacs Preferences file.
;; Add Emacs-Lisp code here that should be executed whenever
;; you start Aquamacs Emacs. If errors occur, Aquamacs will stop
;; evaluating this file and print errors in the *Messags* buffer.
;; Use this file in place of ~/.emacs (which is loaded as well.)

;; Melpa
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line

(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.phtml\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[gj]sp\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.as[cp]x\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.erb\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mustache\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.djhtml\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode))
```

I know this has been asked here:

[Emacs (Aquamacs) web-mode not automatically activating for HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682845/emacs-aquamacs-web-mode-not-automatically-activating-for-html-files)

But there didn't seem to be a concrete answer.

Could anyone may point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a working answer at the mailing list, though it uses magic-mode-alist:

```
(setq magic-mode-alist '(("<!DOCTYPE html" . web-mode)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put those lines at the end of your `.emacs` ?

Comment: Have you asked on the aquamacs mailing list ? Perhaps there is a harcoded setting in their default conf.